# Is it possible to UPDATE a table based on what other columns are showing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, case

The reason for wanting to do this, is I need to group by data set in four different ways, but still need them to be returned as one result set.

For instance.

I can't really think of a practical example, but it's necessary in the one I'm doing. Imagine if i was returning Fruits, Vegetables, Presidents, and Sports but then I want to group all

Fruits together by their name
Vegetabels by their color
Presidents by their party and 
sports by their city. 
(okay, i told you I'd have a bad example)

Anyway, what I was hoping to do was GROUP BY what I would call 'SubClass'. In order to do this 'SubClass' would look to 'RuleClass' to determine what code it should be returning. Is this even possible? Something similiar to this...

```
 UPDATE #FakeTable
 SET SubClass = CASE WHEN RuleClass = 'Fruit' THEN H.NAME
                     WHEN RuleClass = 'Vegetables' THEN H.COLOR
                     WHEN RuleClass = 'President' THEN H.PARTY
                     ELSE H.City
                END
        FROM #Holdings H
        WHERE #FakeTable.SubClass = NULL
```

So this column would esentially pull from another column in a different temp table dependent upon what's in the perceeding column..

Comment: Why do you need a separate table for the subclasses?  Are you storing "Class" in the main table?

Comment: I don't necessarily, I guess. I suppose the better question to ask would be can I have one column pull back different data dependent upon the column next to it. 

That is, if RuleClass was A then SubClass would look for ThisColumn
         if RuleClass was B then SubClass would look for ThatColumn
         and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a `case` statement in a `group by` clause:

```
select class,
       (case when WHEN RuleClass = 'Fruit' THEN H.NAME
                  WHEN RuleClass = 'Vegetables' THEN H.COLOR
                  WHEN RuleClass = 'President' THEN H.PARTY
                  ELSE H.City
        END) as subclass,
      count(*)
from t
group by (case when WHEN RuleClass = 'Fruit' THEN H.NAME
               WHEN RuleClass = 'Vegetables' THEN H.COLOR
               WHEN RuleClass = 'President' THEN H.PARTY
               ELSE H.City
          ENd);
```

You don't need to add it into the table as a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample:

```
UPDATE F
SET SubClass = (CASE WHEN RuleClass = 'Fruit' THEN H.NAME
                     WHEN RuleClass = 'Vegetables' THEN H.COLOR
                     WHEN RuleClass = 'President' THEN H.PARTY
                     ELSE H.City
                END)
FROM #Holdings H
JOIN #FakeTable F ON H.<COLUMNAME>=F.<COLUMNNAME>
WHERE F.SubClass = NULL
```